# Spring @Controller Method Returning Strange Download Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a strange error that gets returned in my Spring MVC application. When I attempt to save a user via a `@RestController` method, the browser seems to interpret the action as a request to download an application. Some info about this issue:

- It is only returned when my application is deployed onto a remote server (works as expected locally)
- This only happens in Internet Explorer

Here is the error:

[image]

Details...

```
OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [7/8/2015 6:56:16 PM] : Activation of mySite.com/myApp/saveUser/100 has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [7/8/2015 6:56:17 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading mySite.com/myApp/saveUser/100 did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
```

Here is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, @PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        userRepo.save(user);
        return "success";
    }
```

The method is pretty straightforward, and I'm not specifying any response headers. Any ideas why this might be happening?

**UPDATE** When capturing the Network Traffic, the POST method Type is `application/x-ms-application` on the remote server, where the Type is standard `text/html` on my local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly setting the `produces` attribute to `"text/html"` seems to have resolved this issue

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser/{id}", produces="text/html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

From the [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

> use of the produces condition ensures the actual content type used to
>   generate the response respects the media types specified in the
>   produces condition